# C# Specialise instance of a class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a problem which i've been googling but can't find the answer to.

Say if you have a class called Account which inherits from a class called AccountInquiry.

If you have an instance of AccountInquiry, can you convert this into an instance of Account without effectively copying it. If not what is the best way to manage this.

Basically a bit of background, when someone fills in a basic Name/Email form on our website is creates an account inquiry, once they've done this they are presented with a 2nd form. If this 2nd form gets fills in the account inquiry is converted into an account.

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: An Account is not an AccountInquiry, so Account should not inherit from AccountInquiry. Rather, give Account a constructor taking an AccountInquiry argument. Apart from that, I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't sound like an `Account` really *is* an `AccountInquiry`. It sounds much more like these should be two entirely separate classes, even if they have some of the same properties.

Be careful before you use inheritance - consider whether it's *really* appropriate or not.

In this case your `AccountInquiry` sounds like it's effectively search criteria for a real `Account` - so you should probably have some *service* class which is able to perform the query, with a method something like:

```
List<Account> FindAccounts(AccountInquiry inquiry)
```

Or possibly just a return type of `Account` if only a single account should be matched. There's no "conversion" going on here - you'd just be using the properties of one object to find another.

(I suspect it should really be *enquiry* rather than *inquiry* by the way, but that's an aside.)

Comment: Thank you, and thanks @James, I had a feeling this might be the case. I had created a Account property on the inquiry as well so removing the inheritance would make sense. I think i'll just treat them as 2 seperate entities and just have the Account as a property on Inquiry. (If it's null then the account has been created).

Comment: I never noticed the typo in the wrong name here so thanks for that! It won't let me accept your answer for a few more minutes but I happily accept your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only up-cast if the original class (Account) is a down-cast from AccountInquiry so, no, that's not possible.

Copying is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

> can you convert this into an instance of Account without effectively copying it

In this scenario, no. `Account` can be cast down to `AccountInquiry` but not vice versa. You could use a tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to make it easier to map fields across though.

As an alternative approach what you could do is make `Account` a property of `AccountInquiry` which would remove the problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but ¿What about this?

```
Account account = new Account();

account.CustomerID = 25;

account.MaxAmount = (decimal)5000.00;
```

And then

```
((AccountInquiry)account).Method = "ListChanges";
((AccountInquiry)account).StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
((AccountInquiry)account).EndDate = DateTime.Today;
```

Then if you need pass to any method that his parameter should be Type you can.